# PrettyPhoto Not Working According to Documentation

Tags: jquery, prettyphoto

I followed all of the documentation on their site, but I can't get this to work.

I copied the script load into my head, activated the script before the body close, and put the prettyPhoto hook on my link.

But when I click on the link, nothing animates, it just opens the full size image the link is pointed to on it's own page.

```
<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/prettyPhoto.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8" />
<script src="js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>




<body>



<a href="superlow.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto"> sldjflkdjsf </a>


<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();
  });
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are there any errors in your console? I mean before you click the link.

Comment: How do I check for errors? I don't see anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me, either your scripts are not found or it's perhaps an encoding issue.

Are you sure that both your scripts are loaded? Because your code works for me here on Safari. NOTE: Please always refer to your browser type and version for such issues.

And you have a document encoding mismatch between your document (set as charset=ISO-8859-1) and your scripts and css (set a utf-8) which could cause problems. Make them both utf-8.

As long both of these things are sound, your example should work.

Comment: Yes I'm using safari. I just fixed the char set issue and it's still having issues: – Retcon just now

Comment: If you use Safari, activate the Develop menu, and right click on the page to inspect the Document. Check for resources or console errors.

Comment: Okay, I found this: Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type image/jpeg.

Comment: One site said this might be because quotations are not around the title of the image, but they are...so I'm not sure why this would happen.  What can I do?

Comment: Eventually add a <!DOCTYPE html> for consistency. But "Resource interpreted as Document" shouldn't cause javascript issues nor the title of the image has anything to do with it. I can only suggest that you restart Safari completely. I have seen javascript getting screwed up sometimes, and restarting with an empty cache was necessary. Other than that don't see any issue with the code itself which again works for me both on Safari 5 and 6.

Comment: Okay, I think I figured out but I don't know how to fix it, it says the scripts aren't loading.  It looks like they can't be found, which is weird, because i have the directory pointed to them in the header.

Comment: You don't know how to fix it? Just check your file and make sure their names match. That's not rocket science...

Comment: sorry, i wasn't thinking clearly because i had copied and pasted from the site and i didn't realize that in their updated version, so i assumed it was a problem with the script itself. it turns out they had just changed the name so it no longer matched their tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

The rel property is supported in all major browsers.

Note: The value "search" is not supported in Opera or Safari.

ref:http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_link_rel.asp

if you count element with 'rel' you will found zero (0).

$("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").length will return zero

thats the problem i think

just use class  instead of rel.. it will work :)

Answer (score 0):

Just try with this

replace href of your anchor tag with xhref

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a[xhref]').each(function() {
       $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('xhref'));
    });
    $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();
});
```

Even if it is show any kind of problem replace

```
$(document).ready(function(){       with 

$(window).bind('load', function(){
```

will solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("a[data-rel='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();            
    });
</script>
```

This works for me just added

> **data-rel** instead of **rel**